# Statistics - Approximating Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Y, the number of accidents per year at a given intersection, is assumed to have a Poisson distribution. Over the past few years, an average of 36 accidents per year have occurred at this intersection. If the number of accidents per year is at least 45, an intersection can qualify to be redesigned under an emergency program set up by the state. Approximate the probability that the intersection in question will come under the emergency program at the end of the next year.

I'm thinking of using the Central Limit Theorem but I'm not exactly sure what that'll look like and the parameters used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the normal approximation (indeed this is due to the Central Limit Theorem) to the Poisson distribution (see [here](http://www.socr.ucla.edu/Applets.dir/NormalApprox2PoissonApplet.html)). You have that $$X \sim Poisson(\lambda=36)$$ (where $\lambda>20$ as required in the link), therefore $$X \sim N(\mu=36, \sigma^2=36)$$ approximately, which can be equivalently formulated as $$Z=\frac{X-36}{\sqrt{36}}=\frac{X-36}{6} \sim N(0, 1)$$ (i.e. $Z$ has the standard normal distribution). Then you want to calculate the probability $$P(X\ge45)\approx P(Z\ge\frac{45-36}{\sqrt{36}})=P(Z\ge \frac{3}{2})=1-\Phi(1.5)=1-0.9332=0.0668$$ or $6.68\%$.